# # linking across two sibling pages doesn't scroll to the right part

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a page using Bootstrap and Django.

I have two pages: Pets and Cats. Both are in the nav bar.
Pets have several sections, including Cats. 
When I click on Cats in the navbar, I want it to load the Pets page and scroll down to the Cats section.

My Pets page has the following code:

```
    <div class="section" id="cats">
        <div class=" centred auto">
            <h1 class="h1">Cats</h1>
            <p>Here you can find pictures of cats</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Cats part of the navbar has the following code:

```
        <li class="active">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'pets' %}#cats">CATS</a>
        </li>
```

Now, when I'm on the Pets page and click Cats in the navbar, it scrolls down to Cats.

When I'm any other page on my website, click Cats in the navbar, it takes me to the Pets page, but does not scroll down.

I'm running a test server and I have tried this on Chromium, Chrome, and Firefox.

Any idea why / how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the code that added CSS to the page turned out to be the culprit.

When the page went live, it worked as intended.

We think it's the issue of dynamic less compiler, but we haven't conducted the tests needed to pinpoint why this is happening in the first place.